# Unexpected type error in hangman class

Tags: java

I am coding a `hangman class` and have a little problem with an `unexpected type error`. This error is in the `this.hidden.charAt(i) = this.original.charAt(i);`. Any help will be appreciated.

```
public class HangmanClass {


        private ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList();
        private String word;
        private final static char HIDECHAR = '*';


        private String original;
        private String hidden;

        public void HangmanWord(String original){
            this.original = original;
            this.hidden = this.hideWord();
        }

        public String getWord() {

            words.add("greetings");
            words.add("cheese");
            words.add("making");
            words.add("juvenile");
            words.add("car");
            word = words.get(new Random().nextInt(words.size()));
            return word;

        }

        private String hideWord() {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
                sb.append(HIDECHAR);
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }

        public boolean checkInput(char input){
            boolean found = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < this.original.length(); i++) {
                if (this.original.charAt(i) == input) {
                    found = true;
                    this.hidden.charAt(i) = this.original.charAt(i);  
                }
            }
              return found;      

        }


    };
```

Comment: There's nothing "unexpected" about your error. In the future, for similar questions, please post the full error message, since it is not worthless gibberish, but rather will often tell you (as it does in this case), exactly what the error is. A critical reading of it will help you and help us.

Answer (score 2):

`String.charAt(int)` cannot be used on the left-hand side of an assignment statement. And you cannot change / mutate `String`s in Java.

Use a `StringBuilder.setCharAt(int index, char ch)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

The `charAt(int)` in `String` cannot be used to assign values. You can use something like:

```
this.hidden.setCharAt(i, this.original.charAt(i));
```

The above works on `StringBuilder`, as `String` is an immutable class in Java. In `String` case you can use something like (generates a new `String` every time):

```
this.hidden = this.hidden.substring(0,i) + this.original.charAt(i) + this.hidden.substring(i);
```